# How to rename existing package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't want to use mv and vim to change each file manually.

How to do that?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12591/how-to-rename-existing-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simply said: AFAIK there is no other way, at least no easy way.

At least no ROS-way. You can obviously use tools like sed, vim's regexp search/replace.
It is usually not that much work in the package itself.

The uglier problems arise from all other packages that use the package and refer to the name.
You will need to change all those, e.g. depends lines, $find lines in launch files, etc.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-13**:
I'm quite sure: No. There could be a tool to rename the package's manifest, etc., within the package, but there are just too many places for the package name. E.g. in any documentation, or any source file in any package, or any yaml or launch file in any package might be references to the package.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-01-13**:
Is there any tool possible for it in the future? Thank you~

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-11**:
Agreed. It is best to pick a good package name to begin with, see http://answers.ros.org/question/2801/when-should-i-split-my-code-into-multiple-packages